# Port Problems on Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I am new to Docker and Google Cloud. I am trying to selfhost on Google Cloud: https://github.com/movie-web/backend.
However, I keep on getting this error:

```
Revision 'backend-movieweb-00006-rjg' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=80 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: Open Cloud Logging  For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
```

I have setup a Docker Hub version of it here which I am using:

- registry-1.docker.io/techygiraffe999/backend-movieweb:1.3.1
- https://hub.docker.com/r/techygiraffe999/backend-movieweb/tags

> - I have allowed ingress and egress rules for the ports through googles firewall as well.
> - I've also tried adding an additional container argument (-p 80:80)
> - I've tried different ports as well

If I launch it directly from the cloud powershell with no other commands like so it works, however the public ip it exposes requires my google account to authenticate it, so I cannot use this method:

```
    -p 80:80 \
    -e MWB_POSTGRES__CONNECTION=[removed_postgrs_url] \
    -e MWB_CRYPTO__SESSION_SECRET="[removed_crypto_session_secret] \
    -e MWB_META__NAME=test-movie-web \
    -e MWB_POSTGRES__SSL=true \
    -e MWB_POSTGRES__MIGRATE_ON_BOOT=true \
    -e MIKRO_ORM_MIGRATIONS_DISABLE_FOREIGN_KEYS=false \
    -e MWB_SERVER__ALLOW_ANY_SITE=true \
    registry-1.docker.io/techygiraffe999/backend-movieweb:1.3.1
```

**Additional Settings:**

- My Auth is set to: `Allow unauthenticated invocations Tick this if you are creating a public API or website.`
- My Ingress Control is set to: `All`

Expected it to run normally, giving the public IP with port 80 exposed.

Comment: We need to see the Dockerfile and deploy command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few considerations:

#### Port problem vs "the container won't start" problem

Given that you've played with port mappings, I suspect the problem might the "startup" itself. "Failed to start and listen" could be a start problem *or* a port problem. I've found my container will sometimes start locally but not on cloud run due to various config issues.

###### Helpful troubleshooting steps:

- Use print statements and check the cloud run log to make sure you're starting as-expected
- Use a logging service like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) to send info about the state of your container and your container environment to you
- Inside your cloud run project, click the YAML tab to inspect the image configuration that run is using to set up your container. I've found often env vars are not passed as-expected.

#### Port mapping

Cloud Run uses port 8080 by default. Cloud run [injects this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/containers#configure-port) into the container as the `PORT` environment variable at startup, so make sure your app inside the container is configured accordingly.

Comment: This answer has little to do with Cloud Run. For example, Cloud Run does not use Docker. Statements like EXPOSE and ENV have no effect in Cloud Run.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. Very fair: this answer was too Docker-focused. I've edited it accordingly, and please feel free to call me out if it needs further improvement.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. However, the OP needs to provide the Dockerfile and deploy command to answer. Once you have that information, update your answer.